# Adding additional outdoor outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

USA, Alabama. Looking for some input on adding an outdoor outlet that’s branched off an existing GFCI one. The current setup is pictured below - the extension cord pictured goes to some string lights (as well as LED Christmas lights seasonally), and I'm about to mount an outdoor TV on the other side of the wall (which is the motivation for this whole project). Ideally, the new outlet will go roughly where the red square is for the TV and lights.

[image: picture of wall with current and proposed outlet locations]

I know ideally I'd just run the wire from inside, but the wall is solid cinderblock which makes that a bit of a hassle, and since it's a short run I'm thinking it'll be easiest to just stay on the outside. Given that, my initial inclination is to use at least 1/2" flexible PVC with liquid tight fittings and 12-gauge THHN wire. I'll be using a wall-mounted non-metallic electrical box with an in-use cover. The existing outlet is GFCI, so I'm covered there.

My biggest question is around that approach with conduit - I've done this plenty indoors but never outdoors, so wanted to make sure that approach isn't going to cause me any issues (and of course happy to take any other suggestions). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is pvc legal? I would want something that doesn't burn, flex (easy) or rigid (pretty).

Comment: what's going on with that 12/2 coming out of the meter box?  free power?  

why even bother with conduit unless you're going to clean up the rest of the mess?